# How can I add a default where clause to all queries for certain models?

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

Is there a way to add a certain where clause by default to certain models in Objection?

### Context

Some of my Objection models use "soft deletes" - rather than actually deleting them from the database, their `deleted_at` column is marked with a timestamp.

By default I'd like to ensure that `where deleted_at is null` is included by default in all my queries so that I don't have to remember to add that in manually.

Is there a way to do this in Objection or Knex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the `query` method in your Model:

```js
class SoftDeleteModel extends Model {
    static query(...args) {
        return super.query(...args).where('deleted_at', null)
    }
}
```

`super.query` refers to the "original" / parent's Objection `query` method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!